# Selenium WebDriver starts and shuts down

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I'm getting this error executing Selenium Java tests:

```
July 11, 2023 6:53:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder getLogOutput
INFO: Driver logs no longer sent to console by default; https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/#setting-log-output
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 93
Current browser version is 114.0.5735.199 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

i used other chrome drivers and it didnt work
can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The Answer already seems to be there in the logs.

```
This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 93 Current browser version is 114.0.5735.199 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Download the latest chromedriver which supports the Chrome Browser version 114

Answer (score 0):

Update [***Selenium***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) version to ***4.6*** or above. [**Selenium Manager**](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) would automatically take care of downloading the matching version of [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) to execute the tests.

So your minimum code block will be:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```